# Utilized a function in SQL developer to calculate the quantity

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, crystal-reports

I use a function in **SQL developer** to calculate the total remain quantity of a compound and show the result by **Crystal Report**. In addition, it is based on the laboratory information management system.

In the figure, different ID means different bottles of the compound. Every action on the bottle would be recorded and specified by the version. The data has been categorized by the compound, its vendor and the changed time (CHANGED_ON).

As in the image,  what I want to show is the "red" total remain quantity. However, I couldn't make it because **the same changed time** for different bottles of the compound as being received. Hence, it is directly summed up the quantity for each bottle (300, 300, 300) instead of one by one (100, 200, 300).

How could I modify the function in the SQL developer or what could I do (Ex: use the formula) in Crystal Report to achieve the request. What I think is to make a loop to recognize the ID and sum up the version quantity to the latest version but I couldn't figure it out...

```
create or replace FUNCTION TOTAL_TEST1
(templatex_id IN NUMBER, vendor in VARCHAR2, chane_on IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER 
IS amount NUMBER(10); 
BEGIN
SELECT SUM(version_qty)
INTO amount
FROM CONSUMABLE_SUMMARY_VIEW TC,
  (SELECT ID,
    MAX(VERSION) MAX_VERSION
  FROM CONSUMABLE_SUMMARY_VIEW
  WHERE TEMPLATE_ID = templatex_id
  AND Vendor_name = vendor
  AND CHANGED_ON    <= chane_on
  GROUP BY ID
  ) TD
WHERE TC.ID = TD.ID
AND TC.VERSION   = TD.MAX_VERSION
AND TC.STATE_NAME NOT LIKE 'Waste';
RETURN amount; END;
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Link is not opening also what exactly you are looking to do?

Comment: Create formula if previous (totalremains) =0 then total remains := used qty + version qty else total remains :=previous (totalremains)-userqty + version qty.

Comment: Is the question to do with SQL Developer, PL/SQL functions, Crystal Reports, or writing a query?

Answer (score 0):

ok your problem is data duplication and because of that your sum is getting affected.

You can solve this in Crystal reports using running total.

Follow below steps:

1. create a running total.
2. Select the field to summarize
3. Give the required summarization
4. Reset on `Change of ID` and place the running total on design instead of direct summarised value.